# move my site to new directory and hide directory name with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have moved my site to /new directory. I don’t want /new in my URL so. how can I deal it.

I've seen similar question but didn't realize the real solution to both redirect to that directory and remove directory name.

This is my current htaccess which has problems:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /new/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /new/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^new/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Nothing to do with php

Comment: Where is the htaccess located?

Comment: htaccess is outside new directory in root

Comment: No answer after 4 months!